# Multiple crop sections with loop in opencv and mouse clicks

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I have obtained region of interests through mouse clicks with OpenCV as

```
roi = [[(276, 756), (940, 828), 'text', 'name'],
       [(1572, 764), (2332, 824), 'text', 'cnic'],
       [(1996, 692), (2052, 752), 'box', 'corporate'],
       [(2300, 692), (2356, 756), 'box', 'individual']]
```

where each tuple is obtained from mouse clicks with OpenCV.

`roi[0][0]` , which is (276, 756), has (x, y) coordinates, so width for the first field named 'name' is 276:940, and height of first field named 'name' is 756:828.

How do I use a for loop to extract cropping of the image like `img[756:828, 276:940]` for all the ROIs?

I found that `roi[0][0]` is `(276, 756)` and `roi[0][0][0]` is 276, but don't know how to implement one loop for all sections.
I will be sending this data to tesseract (OCR).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bot, there is sufficient amount of code above.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to teach you programming. please review [help/on-topic]. you also need to take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for pt1, pt2, _, _ in roi:
    cropped = img[pt1[1]:pt2[1], pt1[0]:pt2[0]]
```